# xcopy invalid number of parameters in powershell only

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to run the following xcopy command

```
xcopy /s /i "./deps/Ultralight/build_release_x64_static_MT/out" "./deps/AppCore/deps/Ultralight"
```

When I run it in command prompt it works.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.630]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>xcopy /s /i "./deps/WebKitLibraries/" "./deps/WebCore/deps/WebKitLibraries/"
File not found - ./deps/WebKitLibraries/
0 File(s) copied

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

When I run it in powershell it fails

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Jonathan> xcopy /s /i "./deps/WebKitLibraries/" "./deps/WebCore/deps/WebKitLibraries/"
Invalid number of parameters
PS C:\Users\Jonathan>
```

I don't see any issues with the syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: Use backslash `\\` instead of `/` `xcopy /s /i ".\deps\WebKitLibraries\" ".\deps\WebCore\deps\WebKitLibraries\"`

Comment: Neither of the provided answers explains the problem properly. Windows fully supports both / and \ path separators.

Comment: Since you are not willing to try any of the solutions given, I have removed my answer.

Comment: That’s fine because your answer had nothing to do with the question anyways lol

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash `\` instead of forward slash `/`. It will work. Don't know why it prints `Invalid number of parameters`.

`xcopy /s /i ".\deps\WebKitLibraries\" ".\deps\WebCore\deps\WebKitLibraries\"`